# How to ssh through the gitlab subdomain URL

Tags: nginx, docker, gitlab

From this question I'd like to ask more of it

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75527943/unable-to-git-clone-from-self-hosted-gitlab-instance-with-custom-port-6022

Solved the problem that I need to open the port on the cloud service. Now the next problem is how do I clone using the `gitlab.gitlabinstance.com` URL instead of the host machine IP. Example :

`ssh git@x.x.x.x -p 6022`

`x.x.x.x` is the host machine IP and it works.

I'd like to ssh through

`ssh git@gitlab.mygitlabinstance.com -p 6022`

and I got this output where the IP addresses are different than the host machine IP (z.z.z.z, y.y.y.y, a,a,a,a)

where the `z.z.z.z`, `y.y.y.y`, `a.a.a.a` are the public addresses

```
 ssh -vT gitlab.example.com -p6022
OpenSSH_8.5p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/Sam/.ssh/config
debug1: /c/Users/Sam/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for gitlab.example.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.example.com [z.z.z.z] port 6022.
debug1: connect to address z.z.z.z port 6022: Connection timed out
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.example.com [y.y.y.y] port 6022.
debug1: connect to address y.y.y.y port 6022: Connection timed out
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.example.com [a:a:a:a] port 6022.
debug1: connect to address a:a:a:aport 6022: Network is unreachable
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.example.com [a:a:a:a] port 6022.
debug1: connect to address 2606:4700:3032::ac43:97fa port 6022: Network is unreachable
ssh: connect to host gitlab.example.com port 6022: Network is unreachable
```

is there any solution for this?

Comment: Why does not `gitlab.example.com` point to 172.13.2.1?

Comment: i dont know @vidarlo when i try to ssh into `example.com` it shows the same IP address as y.y.y.y

Comment: Did you set up DNS?

Comment: no @vidarlo i didnt

Comment: Why do you expect `gitlab.example.com` to work if you've not configured DNS? I don't get head or tails of your question.

Comment: where can i set it up @vidarlo is it on the nginx?

Comment: i use alibaba cloud for the DNS setup @vidarlo

Comment: Can you give us the *real* domain and *real* IP addresses involved?